# #Button new on click listener

Tags: android

I wonder that if I have two buttons, and every time I press the first button I call the method `secondButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener)`. My question is when I set the new listener for the second button every time I press the first button, what happens to the old listener is it still in the memory ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Activity owns button, button has a listener that is owned by Activity, if both can't be accessed from root, then theoretically they should be GCed.

there is a better way.

```
secondButton.performClick();
```

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#performClick()

Hope it helps.